# Jasmine Unit Test Angular-Cookie

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm having trouble testing the angular-cookie module. This is because of the odd way the 'GET' method has been implemented, in comparison to its' other methods (Note how the 'GET' method does not have a method declaration):

```
ipCookie(cookieName)         // GET
ipCookie.remove(cookieName)  // DELETE
```

As a result, the following code:

```
var ipCookie = jasmine.createSpyObj('ipCookie', ['remove'])
ipCookie.and.returnValue(true)
```

Fails with the message:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'ipCookie.and.returnValue')
```

Whereas the code:

```
var ipCookie = jasmine.createSpyObj('ipCookie', ['remove'])
ipCookie.remove.and.returnValue(true)
```

Works as expected. How exactly do I test these 2 methods?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are using ngCookies? As far as I can see there is no ipCookie service in ngCookies. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg The library is called 'angular-cookie', it is different to ngCookies. I require this library because the standard ngCookies does not allow setting an expiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of Cristian's answer, I was able to mock out both the `get` and `delete` methods on one mock object.

```
describe('Service: service', function() {
  var ipCookieSpy;

  beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {
    ipCookieSpy = jasmine.createSpy('ipCookieGet');
    ipCookieSpy.remove = jasmine.createSpy('ipCookieRemove');
    $provide.value('ipCookie', ipCookieSpy);
  }));

  it('Sanity checks the ipCookie spy', inject(function(ipCookie) {
    ipCookie();
    expect(ipCookieSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    ipCookie.remove();
    expect(ipCookieSpy.remove).toHaveBeenCalled()
  }));
});
```

Comment: Amazing stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find a single way to spy on `ipCookie` which allows me to test all its' methods. To test the "GET" and "DELETE" methods, I have split my test suite into 2 and have implemented 2 different ways of spying on the module.

The first test suite allows me to test the module's methods:

```
describe('Service: service', function () {
  beforeEach(module('app', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('ipCookie', jasmine.createSpyObj('ipCookie', ['remove']));
  }));
```

Usage: `expect(ipCookie.remove).toHaveBeenCalledWith('cookieName');`

The second test suite allows me to mock the module's nameless "GET" method:

```
describe('Service: service', function () {
  beforeEach(module('app', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('ipCookie', jasmine.createSpy('ipCookie'));
  }));
```

Usage: `ipCookie.and.returnValue(mockCookie);`

Comment: I was able to mock out both with one spy object. See my answer below. It's based on your post - thank you for the inspiration!